# Send PDF as attachment via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, email, pdf, acrobat

I have a PDF in Acrobat with the following JavaScript in a button's mouse down method.  The code prompts for the mail client (in my case, Outlook or Webmail).  When I select Outlook, a new Outlook message is formed with the appropriate TO:, SUBJECT:, and BODY: areas but the file where the button resides it not attached.  Documentation from https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/dynamically-setting-submit-e-mail-address seems to indicate that the file is attached automatically.  I'd like to code it so the PDF is attached.  The e message does not return any text.

```
try
{
    var myDoc = event.target;
    var cToAddr = "rrose@bi.com";
    var cSubLine = "Test Email";
    var cBody = "Email body text";
    this.mailDoc({bUI:false, cTo:cToAddr, cCC:"", cSubject:cSubLine, cMsg:cBody});
} catch(e){app.alert(e)}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1) When you want to do something when the user clicks the button, use the mouseUp event (and not the mouseDown); clicking is releasing the mouse, not pressing it.

2) `event.target` is the button field, and not the document. The document is `this`.

3) I highly recommend to download the Acrobat SDK from the Adobe website. There you find the documentation for Acrobat JavaScript; have a good look at it, in particular at the description of `mailDoc()`, and its security restrictions.

4) See 3) …